# Enabling remote access to ArangoDB web interface

Tags: nginx, remote-access, port-forwarding

I am currently experimenting with ArangoDB installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 server.  One of the really neat things about ArangoDB is the nicely designed web interface it provides for managing the database.  On my Windows installation I can access it by browsing to `http://127.0.0.1:8529/`.  On my server I have ensured that UFW has been configured to accept connections on port 8529.  When I Telnet to localhost 8529 on my server I can connect.  However, I am unable to do so from my Windows desktop machine.  Nor am I able to reach the Web UI by browsing to 
`https://user:password@ip.for.my.server:8529`.

I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be tell me how to do this - if at all it is possible. There is perhaps port forwarding involved in some way but if that requires me to configure Nginx on my server somehow I have no prior experience with doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installation ArangoDB only listens to localhost, which is set by default.
To expose the service to another network, you have to adjust the ArangoDB configuration.

Edit the configuration. Default location /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf (Ubuntu)

```
#endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:8529     // comment out that line
endpoint = tcp://192.168.123.4:8529  // add your servers IP address
```

Or expose it to all networks (if wanted):

```
endpoint = tcp://0.0.0.0:8529  // listen to all networks
```

Then perform a restart of the ArangoDB service:

```
sudo systemctl restart arangodb3
```